# C++ Explicit type is missing, declaration is incompatible, expected a type specifier

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm trying to create a 3D cube using the iostream to read a txt file (this is an assignment). I declared Cube::Load as a static boolean in the cube.h and implemented the code in cube.cpp. After doing this I tried to call the method in FirstGL.cpp but am met with 3 errors.

1. Cube = Explicit type is missing (int assumed)
2. Load = Declaration is incompatible with "bool Cube::Load(char* path)
3. ("cube.txt") Expected a type specifier

The notes I've been given tell me I can use Cube::Load("cube.txt") as I've already given the type in the cube header file.

**FirstGL.cpp**

```
#include "FirstGL.h"

Cube::Load("cube.txt");
```

**Cube.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include "GL\freeglut.h"

#include "structures.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

class Cube
{
private:
    static Vertex* indexedVertices[];
    static Color* indexedColors[];
    static GLushort* indices[];
    static int numVertices, numColors, numIndices;
    GLfloat _rotation;
    static bool Load(char* path);


public:
    Cube(void);
    ~Cube(void);

    void Draw();
    void Update();

};
```

**Cube.cpp**

```
#include "Cube.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Vertex* Cube::indexedVertices[] = nullptr; /*{ 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, // v0,v1,
-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, // v2,v3
1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, // v4,v5
-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1 }; // v6,v7*/
Color* Cube::indexedColors[] = nullptr; /*{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, // v0,v1,
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, // v2,v3
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, // v4,v5
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //v6,v7*/
GLushort* Cube::indices[] = nullptr; /*{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, // front
0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 0, // right
0, 5, 6, 6, 1, 0, // top
1, 6, 7, 7, 2, 1, // left
7, 4, 3, 3, 2, 7, // bottom
4, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4 }; // back*/

int Cube::numVertices = 0;
int Cube::numColors = 0;
int Cube::numIndices = 0;

Cube::Cube()
{


}


Cube::~Cube()
{
}

void Cube::Draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(_rotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, indexedVertices);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, indexedColors);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glFlush(); //Flushes scene we just drew to the graphics card
    glutSwapBuffers(); // Initialises double Buffering
    glPopMatrix();
}

void Cube::Update()
{

    //if (rotation >= 360.0f)
        //rotation = 0.0f;
    _rotation += 0.1f;


}

bool Cube::Load(char* path)
{
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(path);

    if (!inFile.good())
    {
        cerr << "Can't open texture file " << path << endl;
        return false;
    }

    inFile >> numVertices;

    indexedVertices = new Vertex[numVertices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        inFile >> indexedVertices[i];
    }

    inFile >> numColors;

    indexedColors = new Color[numColors];

    for (int i = 0; i < numColors; i++)
    {
        inFile >> indexedColors[i];
    }

    inFile >> numIndices;

    indices = new GLushort[numIndices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; i++)
    {
    inFile >> indices[i];
    }

    inFile.close();

    return true;
}
```

FirstGL.cpp only includes the error line. Every constructor and header file is connected (before I had to use txt file the cube class worked fine). Sorry if I included too much code or didn't indent properly, it's my first time using this site. Thank you.

Comment: Does `FirstGL.cpp` include `Cube.h`(`#include "Cube.h"`)?

Comment: FirstGL.h includes Cube.h

Comment: Just a quick observation - You don't need to include iostream, fstream and string inside of Cube.cpp while it's already included in Cube.h (that is included in Cube.cpp). And have You tried replacing `static bool Load(char* path)` with `static bool Load(const char* path)` to make it work? This may seem nothing but compilers can be pushy about such things.

Comment: Load is a private member of Cube, so you can't call Cube::Load.

Comment: The notes I get says "Moving back to your FirstGL.cpp file, we need to call this new load method to populate the cube data. With a static method you don't need an instance of the class to be created before you call it, this is the whole point of static methods, to exist without an instance of the class. This means, you can call this new load method to load the cube data for all cubes before you actually create cubes in your constructer. Cube::Load("cube.txt");" Changing to const made no change at all, neither did making Load public.